# A protected by password directory started to redirect to the home!

Tags: apache-2.2, directory

Everything was working perfectly a few hours ago, but now, when I try to access one protected directory in one of my websites hosted on my dedicated server that runs Cent OS and apache, it just redirectos to the website home page.

What is strange is that I changed nothing before this starting to happen.
I even renamed the directory and created another user for it, but the problem continues.

The directory htaccess looks like this:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "something here"
AuthUserFile "/home/sitename/.htpasswds/public_html/directoryname/passwd"
require valid-user
```

The headers are strange. I got this:

```
Server Response:
http://www.webiste.net/protecteddirectory


HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Tue, 17 May 2011 01:34:03 GMT
Server: Apache
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="type your password"
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.6
Set-Cookie: cookielang=
Set-Cookie: Poweredlang=pt; expires=Wed, 18-May-2011 02:44:03 GMT
Location: http://www.website.net/
Content-Length: 733
Content-Type: text/html
```

Answer (score 1):

Check your .htaccess in main directory, looks like it contains some RewriteRules